# Метод середины квадратов с помощью побитового сдвига

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2010

Добрый день. Подскажите, как реализовать метод середин квадратов на си. Есть пример кода функции на паскале:

```
var xi: longint; {глобальная переменная; сюда изначально 
            должна быть помещена затравка}
function rrsch:real;
begin
  xi:=((xi*xi) shr 7) and $3FFF;    {28 бит - квадрат, 14 бит - число}
  if xi=0 then begin
    Random( …);     {заносит в RandSeed очередное псевдослучайное число - затравку}
    xi:=RandSeed and $3FFF;
  end;
  rrsch:=xi/$4000;          {двоичное 01000000 00000000}
end;
```

Если, например, брать середину квадрата от числа 4824, то 4824^2=23270976 нам нужно будет взять из этого числа 2709. Как я понял это нужно сделать с помощью оператора побитового сдвига, однако реализовать его у меня так и не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Beryllium](/users/6295/beryllium)](/users/6295/beryllium), насколько я понял Вы хотите получить средние биты произведения. Т.е. для 32-битовых целых Вам нужны средние 16 бит.

Не хочу спорить о правильности программы на паскале, просто продемонстрирую это извлечение в примерчике на Си.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  u_int x = 4824, mid, sqr;

  sqr = x*x;
  mid = (sqr>>8) & 0xffff;  // вот это Вам и надо делать

  printf ("x = 0x%x sqr = 0x%x mid = 0x%x\n",
      x,sqr,mid);
  exit (0);
}
```

В переменной `mid` интересующие Вас 16 бит. Кстати, наглядно все это только в шестнадцатиричных цифрах.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc midsqr.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
x = 0x12d8 sqr = 0x1631640 mid = 0x6316
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Пардон. Только что обратил внимание, что вас интересую 14-разрядные числа. Тогда формула  `mid = ((x*x) >> 7) & 0x3fff` безусловно верна. Это хорошо видно при выводе в двоичном виде

```
  x = 4824 & 0x3fff;
  sqr = x*x;
  mid = (sqr>>7) & 0x3fff;
  printf ("x = 0x%x sqr = 0x%x mid = 0x%x\n",
      x,sqr,mid);

  char xstr[64], qstr[64], mstr[64];
  my_llstr((long long)x,2,0,xstr);
  my_llstr((long long)sqr,2,0,qstr);
  my_llstr((long long)mid,2,0,mstr);
  printf ("x = %s\nsqr = %s\nmid = %s\n",
      xstr,qstr,mstr);
```

А это результаты (без ведущих нулей)

```
для 28/14 бит: x = 0x12d8 sqr = 0x1631640 mid = 0x62c
x = 1001011011000
sqr = 1011000110001011001000000
mid = 11000101100
```

Так что, не волнуйтесь. IMHO у Вас все правильно вычисляется, просто проблемы с наглядным отображением результата.

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз то что нужно. Думаю с 32-битной сеткой будет даже лучше.